# javascript - RegEx only matches some numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code:

```
var reIsNumeric = /[0-9]/g;
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(1));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(2));  // false
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(3));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(4));  // false
```

Does anyone know why only the odd numbers would return `true`? Am I losing my mind?

Comment: `test` modifies the state of the regex.

Comment: if you change the order of the numbers, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I see now... could you elaborate on what it modifies?

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 2):

Take the `g` out

```
var reIsNumeric = /[0-9]/;
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(1));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(2));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(3));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(4));  // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tap3nfx/1/

The reason is because the `g` modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

So basically the value that will return true is not what you would expect but the same regex as yours does work as expected see below.

```
var reIsNumeric = /[0-9]/g;
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(1));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(22));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(333));  // true
console.log(reIsNumeric.test(4444));  // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tap3nfx/2/

Comment: Can you explain why?